# what is span frown.is frown is new html5 attribute

Tags: css, html

I have seen bellow tag in  wordpress 404 page .is frown is attribute. why it is used.

```
<span frown>:(</span>
```

Thanks

Comment: Its a class ...
you can use it directly to style your DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a HTML (5) attribute. It's used by Wordpress (CSS selector: `span[frown]`) to attach styles to that element.

Comment: so you mean we can add what ever like foo or any think.is there any advantage

Comment: If you don't mind using non-standard HTML attributes, you can even practice this: `<div mystyle secret>Secret text</div>` + CSS: `div[mystyle][secret]{display:none;}`. The more convential way is to use class names: `<div class="mystyle secret">..</style>` + CSS: `div.mystyle.secret{display:none}`

Comment: if you want to stick to the HTML5 standard, all custom attributes should start with `data-`. Thus to be HTML5 compliant, the given example should actually be `<span data-frown>`. None of the browsers actually care about this right now, so you can get away without the `data-`, but best practice would be to include it if you're making your own attributes.